# How do I make sidebar elements on a wordpress website sticky for a certain section of the website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, sidebar

Here's an example to better illustrate my question:

[enter link description here](https://www.divein.com/diving/scuba-tank/)

Check their sidebar from desktop. Different section of the side bar becomes sticky for each product review then slides up to give space for the next one.

How do I achieve this on wordpress?

I believe there's some sort of javascript code at play to make such dynamic changes and the scroll event listener is somehow involved.
Any help is appreciated. I am not that savvy with tech and programming.

I tried tinkering in inspect element with the css to implement it but can't go past making the entire sidebar sticky.

Answer (score 0):

stickied elements will only be sticky within their parent element.  If you wrap each sidebar and the content you want it to scroll with in a parent div, you can just set the outermost element of the sidebars to sticky

```css
.container {
  border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.content {
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class=sidebar>sidebar</div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class=sidebar>sidebar</div>

</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class=sidebar>sidebar</div>

</div>
```